# jQuery function not attached to dom elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dom-events

I am trying build a web page that will construct elements from JSON file and attach click function to those elements.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $.ajax({
        url: 'database.php',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (datas) {
            (datas);
            for (var x = 0; x < datas.data.length; x++) {
                var id = datas.data[x].ID;
                var ip = datas.data[x].IP;
               var ips='<div class="ip"><span id="ids">'+id+'</span><span id="number">'+ip+'</span></div>';
               $('#left').append(ips);

            }
        }
    });

$('.ip').click(function () {
alert($(this).children('#ids').text());
});

});
```

the code above builds the elements successfully but the click function is not working.

Comment: the ids you assign to the spans aren't unique. While that may not be the cause of your problem, it's definitely a bad idea. Every element with an ID should have an ID that's unique to the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function instead, it is used to apply event handlers to elements that are not yet created.

Where you have your current `click` setup, try something like this instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ip', function(){
    alert($(this).children('#ids').text());
});
```

---

As @Pete has suggested, it is not a good idea to assign the same `id` attributes within a loop, they should be unique to the document. Consider finding them via `class` names instead, so you could alert something like:

```
alert($(this).children('.MyIdsSpan').text());
```

Comment: I have anothe question,in what scenarios we can use the live() function?

Comment: Live is deprecated in favor of `$(document).on()`

Comment: @ShalyzaMansor: As Dennis has said, `live` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7, this is explained in the [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) documentation, where you are encouraged to use `on` instead